# How to compile two or more css in one file using php in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing Wordpress site, in that,  having two or more styles, for example, I having style1.css, style2.css, style3.css but these three files should be in one css folder with name style.css. How can I do this with use of PHP in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

The wp-scss sass plugin for WordPress is great for this. If you aren't using a gulp/grunt -ish build chain, you can just use this plugin. You put your .scss files (just rename your css files to scss) in the directory as instructed and it will compile them for you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-scss/

Comment: How do I add styles for a widget ?  I'm having two different sites having two different styles once I drag and drop that widget section that should take specific style what I choose.How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing with you one example for compile two or more css in one file in wordpress. Please go through in below example,

The wp_enqueue_style() function uses the following format and parameters:

```html
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src = false, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' );
```

In your case, you could try the following:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function namespace_theme_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mamies-wafers-bootstrap-min',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mamies-wafers-carousel',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/carousel.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mamies-wafers-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), '', null, 'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'namespace_theme_stylesheets' );
```

f you plan on minifying your CSS, it's always best to use [wp_register_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) for each stylesheet first, and then enqueue it.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Proper way to register and enqueue scripts and styles
 */    
function namespace_theme_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_style( 'mamies-wafers-bootstrap-min',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'mamies-wafers-carousel',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/carousel.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'mamies-wafers-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), '', null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mamies-wafers-bootstrap-min' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mamies-wafers-carousel' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mamies-wafers-style' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'namespace_theme_stylesheets' );
```